# How to display an image with matplotlib and sleep thereafter - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to be able to bring up a figure containing two images with plt.show(block=False).  I want non-blocking because I need to continue execution while the images (figure) loads.  If I immediately call time.sleep(x), x being any amount of time, the figure hangs and does not display the images.  However, if I immediately call input("x") instead, x being whatever string, the images load properly and the program waits for user input.  Waiting indefinitely on user input does not work for what I need, but time.sleep does not do what I want (hangs the figure).  I want to get the behavior of calling input(), without actually waiting for any user input, with the functionality of time.sleep().

Essentially, I want to display a couple of images, and allow the user to press the enter key to continue right away, OR wait some amount of seconds and continue automatically (this is inside a loop which will bring up another couple of images and repeat).  I am getting user input during time.sleep() with msvcrt.getch() (I'm on windows), which is just using the key hit during sleep that is in the buffer (I think...)

I have tried calling plt.show() in a thread, but matplotlib (tk backend?) is not thread-safe, so I get the same hanging issue (no images displayed).  Also, I have read cv2.imshow() is not thread-safe as well.

I am open to any way of doing this...maybe matplotlib and msvcrt is not the way to go, but they do what I need separately, I just can't get them to work together.

Basically, what I am trying to do:

```
loop
   plt.show()
   time.sleep()
   if key_hit:
      if key is Enter
         continue
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue completely, but are you aware of [`plt.waitforbuttonpress`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.waitforbuttonpress.html)

Comment: I think you should use plt.draw() instead of plt.show()

Comment: plt.waitforbuttonpress does seem to fit the pseudo code I put up.  I'll give it a shot.  I tried dropping in plt.draw instead of show, but nothing is displayed.  Code executes as if the statement wasn't even there.  I'll check the docs though.  Maybe I am using it incorrectly. Any ideas on other image display libraries?  Thanks for the help.